# What HQ to take for my 1500pts codex Space Marine army list

Tags: warhammer-40k

I have the following list

- 10-man Tactical Squad (flamer + rocket launcher) + Rhino
- 10-man Tactical Squad (flamer + rocket launcher) + Rhino
- 10-man Tactical Squad (flamer + rocket launcher)
- 10-man Assault Squad (Sergent has combat shield + fist)
- 10-man Scout Squad (Sergent has power weapon) => Outflank with lots of combat blade + shotguns
- 5-man shooting Terminator Squad
- Dreadnought Multi-melta
- Dreadnought Plasma Cannon

What HQ should I take to compliment my army list?

Currently, I am fielding

- Librarian in Terminator armor (no other wargear).

The total is exactly 1500.

I am planning to fight against Chaos, Necron, lots of infantry Imperial Guard, lots of Las-cannon Blood Angel.

Comment: I'm confused as to the question, exactly.  You have a 1500 point list, which includes your HQ selection (Librarian).  You're asking for an HQ to take.  Are you asking for an additional HQ for higher point games, or for a replacement of the Librarian?

Comment: I am looking for a replacement of the librarian. In my previous games, he got singled-out and killed too fast.

Comment: He's an independent character, so you could stick him with the Terminators for cover.  As a bonus, it lets him Gate of Infinity them around the map so that they can shoot at appropriate targets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Captains and Masters are OK.  They are good at combat, but they don't really do anything to support the army.  They make a good second HQ choice unless you want to run bikes as troops.

Chaplains can boost a single squad, but he'll really only get one or two opportunities to earn his points.

Master of The Forge can be good, but he can get pretty expensive and never is quite as efficient as a Captain or Master.  Take him only if you want to run a list with 6 dreadnoughts.

The Librarian is the best generic HQ option for this list. Join him to the Terminator Squad and he will be protected by the independent character rules.  I'd personally just run him in power-armor to save on points, but Terminator armor with a storm shield is also a good setup.  Power-wise, I'd give him Null Zone and Gate of Infinity.  Gate will allow him to move the terminators around the board and Null Zone will help against any annoying invulnerable save death star units

If you want a good special character option to run with your list, I think Shrike would be the best fit.  Infiltrating fleeting terminators or assault squads can be lots of fun.

Comment: Can I have two librarians and Gate twice in one turn?

Comment: @DatChu Without the codex in front of me; I think you technically could.  But this would be a very dangerous move, and I wouldn't advise doing it.  It's two chances to loose a model, two chances for perils, and two chances for mishaps.

Answer (score 0):

Marneus Calgar equipped with either Flamers or Storm Bolters is the only way to replace your librarian in style. However, DO NOT LEAVE HIM BY HIMSELF! Keep him with the terminators and you will be sweet (I prefer Honour Guard with Calgar but terminators function the same way)

Comment: What makes you think the OP is playing Ultramarines?

Comment: I don't play Ultramarines. DA power armour, SW power armour or something similar. Also, Marneus cannot take options aside from the terminator armour suit.